# Issues in building zeppelin from source

Tags: apache-zeppelin

I am trying to build zeppelin from source with spark 1.5.0 and my build failed with below error

```
[bala@server incubator-zeppelin]$ mvn install -DskipTests -Dspark.version=1.5.0 -Dhadoop.version=2.6.0 -Drat.skip=true

...
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:bower (bower install) on project zeppelin-web: Failed to run task: 'bower --allow-root install' failed. (error code 1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1]     http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :zeppelin-web
```

Not sure why this is happening.

I have not yet installed hadoop in this machine but I do not think this will be an issue while building. But I have spark 1.5 installed.

Here are other details

```
bala@server incubator-zeppelin]$ bower --version
1.5.2
[bala@server incubator-zeppelin]$ npm --version
1.3.6
[bala@server incubator-zeppelin]$ node --version
v0.10.36
[bala@server incubator-zeppelin]$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-   22T17:27:37+05:30)
Maven home: /home/bala/Software/apache-maven-3.3.3
Java version: 1.8.0_60, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /home/bala/Software/jdk1.8.0_60/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64", arch: "amd64",    family: "unix"
[bala@server incubator-zeppelin]$
```

Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this. This happened due to the missing .bowerrc file with proper proxy settings in it. Once, I created this file, the building process completed successfully.

Thanks